# Django MongoDB Engine error when running tellsiteid

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, django-nonrel

SO I created a django project and app as per the tutorial and I have all the dependencies necessarry for MongoDB Engine it all seemed to be working fine and dandy till I tried enabling the admin interface.

I uncommented the require bits, and added 'django_mongodb_engine' and 'djangotoolbox' to the apps section in settings.py

When I try to get into localhost:8000/admin I get an error:

"AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'1' instead). Please make sure your SITE_ID contains a valid ObjectId string."

After some googling apparently I have to run manage.py tellsiteid and it'll spit me an ID I can use within my settings.py that will make the error go away, but when I try to run manage.py tellsiteid I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 14, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager    utility.execute()
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/management/commands/tellsiteid.py", line 8, in handle_noargs
site_id = self._get_site_id()
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/management/commands/tellsiteid.py", line 19, in _get_site_id
return Site.objects.get().id
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/holografix/.virtualenvs/django_nonrel_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get
% self.model._meta.object_name)
django.contrib.sites.models.DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't created any Site yet. Run `manage.py syncdb` to create one.

Comment: `manage.py syncdb` raises the same exception even after dropping the database and starting fresh. This worked for me: 1) drop the database 2) create a `Site` as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/9780984/76900 3) add `SITE_ID`to settings 4) run `manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 12):

You can create your site, and then, get the id:

```
python ./manage.py shell

>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> s = Site()
>>> s.save()
```

and then:

```
python ./manage.py tellsiteid
```

Comment: So, what if we accidentally ran this more than once, can you clear it?

Answer (score 12):

If you do not need the `sites` functionality (which is very probable) simply turn off `django.contrib.sites` app and it will fix MongoDB issues related to the SITE_ID:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (   
    (...)
    # 'django.contrib.sites',  # Comment this out
    (...)
)
```

Comment: Very usefull for me as simple as it sounds! Got a mess before that! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

have you tried this: http://django-mongodb.org/troubleshooting.html#site-id-issues

Answer (score 3):

For some reason none of the solutions here worked for me. `python ./manage.py tellsiteid`, there was no `django_site` collection, and commenting out `'django.contrib.sites'` caused weird errors.

Grabbing the ID from the shell worked for me though, detailed here:

https://gist.github.com/ielshareef/2986459
or here [Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist)

```
python ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site().save()
>>> Site.objects.all()[0].id
u'4fe7aa759e654e2662000000'
```

Put it in `settings.py` and everything worked great!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this during my setup the other day.

Basically you need to logo into a mongo shell and lookup your siteid then add it your      settings.py

log into a mongo shell

```
mongo
```

select your db

```
use *name*
```

then do a find() on django_site

```
db.django_site.find()
```

Then open your settings.py and edit the site_ID ="" line (mine is below)

```
SITE_ID = u'4f1f82011d41c81e5c00001d'
```

That should get you up and running

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you havent created a site yet, to do so you need to run the command

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

This creates the site, now you need to add its site_id in your settings file. Go get the site id, connect to mongodb engine that is running, and run the following commands

```
use mydatabase --/# or whatever name you have for your database.
db.django_site.find()
```

you will get something like

```
ObjectId("4f4e968adea3b3b30c00001d")
```

then in your settings file, put

```
site_id = u'4f4e968adea3b3b30c00001d'
```

and the admin interface should work. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

I use `manage.py syncdb` and then `manage.py tellsiteid` but still display error.

I finally solve it by dropping the database and sync again.

Hope this can help someone:)

Answer (score 0):

sudo python manage.py shell

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site().save()
Site.objects.all()[0].id
u'53aa6456984edd0d5e547e03'
```

Put it in settings.py
    SITE_ID = u'53aa6456984edd0d5e547e03'