# Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

The site was working very well until I clicked "log out" on my app. After that, the website would give me this error:
DoesNotExist at /login/
Site matching query does not exist.

I searched everywhere and the only solution I get relates to setting up the site framework, SITE_ID, etc. I think those items on my computer are fine, but I can't find a walkthrough/guide to help me check on them.

What's the problem and how can it be fixed?

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/home/dotcloud/nhs.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to login to the admin site ? it seems that your django_site table is empty. you need at least one entry over there

Comment: No, I can't log in to the admin site. It gives me the same error at /admin/

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If you don't have a site defined in your database and django wants to reference it, you will need to create one.

From a `python manage.py shell` :

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
new_site = Site.objects.create(domain='foo.com', name='foo.com')
print (new_site.id)
```

Now set that site ID in your settings.py to SITE_ID

Comment: I can't get the python manage.py shell to work. It gives me this error: 
python: can't open file 'manage.py'

Comment: I deleted the first project from set up and got the app from the previous owner (website admin changes every year for this.)

Comment: Well this sounds like a bigger problem than just missing a database entry. If you cant even run manage.py, then you can't even start the dev server to test locally. Are you sure you are running this within the project location that actually contains the manage.py script?

Comment: I'm probably not running within the project location. It's currently running in C:\Users\MyName>. But the manage.py file for this app is in C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Websites\NHS .

Comment: Well that would be it then. You need to be in your project location. The shell is telling you there is no `manage.py` in your current directory

Comment: how do I change the project location? Move the folders to another location?

Comment: oh that (like I said I'm new to this). I tried python manage.py shell in the right location and it tells me:
Error: No module named chronograph.

Comment: Then the project has extra library dependencies that you dont have installed on your machine yet. You will need to install all 3rd party requirements that are being used. But at least you got manage.py to run

Comment: Ok, the chronograph files were in a different folder... manage.py runs correctly

Comment: the second line of the code you gave in the initial post (first one works) gives this error: unable to open database file

Comment: You dont have your project even configured, with your database. What database is it using? Did you take the steps to actually set it up? Did you run `syncdb` ? It sounds to me like you just copied this project over and started trying to use it?

Comment: yes, I just copied the project over (I had a tech guy overseeing stuff. guess he forgot about configuring?) it's using dotcloud. is this the set up?: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Yea that first part is about creating a new project. You are probably at [this step here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) .

Comment: Actually, i see there is a dotcloud-specific doc. It says you are using sqlite3 for your database? So I assume that this project is properly deployed to dotcloud, but you are trying to run it locally as a dev server, and your sqlite does not exist locally: http://olddocs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/django/#use-a-sqlite-database

Comment: ok, followed the dotcloud instructions. the settings.py , url.py, and other things I needed to edit were already correct.

Comment: I am assuming having run syncdb, you now have a local database that can be used.

Comment: retried the original code. same error. it stops at a file in  Django, db, backends, sqlite3, base,py at this line: self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs) .

Comment: post the database configuration from your settings.py, in your question

Comment: syncdb ran in cygdriver (I think it's a Linux simulator or something along those lines since I'm on Windows) but it still has the database error in the C:\ run.

Comment: ok, I posed the database config back at the top of this question

Comment: You are using the same settings as your server (as opposed to a local version). Are you sure `/home/dotcloud/nhs.db` is accessible locally as a valid path? That is the physical location it wants to create the sqlite3 database. That is a UNIX path, yet you are running this under a `C:\` command prompt

Comment: /home/dotcloud/nhs.db is not in the sqlite3 folder or anywhere in the python27 folder (is folder the same as database?) should I have downloaded it?

Comment: No. It would get created by the syncdb process if you did not already have an existing database. My point is that you would need to change that to a valid path for your local system.

Comment: oh, I see. ok, I changed the path to the place nhs.db is actually stored.

Comment: when I do dotcloud run etc. syncdb it has an error: can't open file 'current/nhs/manage.py' I've tried to fix it (copy the manage.py and post it one folder up, move directories with cd) but nothing seems to work

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there are too many factors here. Its a copied project, and I have major doubts that your environment is correct, or the paths. its just not currently configured for your local environment.

Comment: ok, I guess I'll have do this with the previous owner. thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks! All the other answers never mentioned changing the SITE_ID in settings.py

Comment: Is there not a way to call `Site.objects.create` other than directly from the management shell? It seems odd that this is not documented clearly, yet it is vital to setting up the "sites framework".

Comment: I don't know what caused it to happen. It is supposed to happen automatically when creating a new project. This was also 2.5 years ago. so maybe it has since been resolved.

Comment: Warning, if you already defined your site in /admin/sites/ and don't want to create a new one, here's how **to get an existing SITE_ID**:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21084927/673991

Answer (score 36):

Table `django_site` must contain a row with the same value than `id` (by default equals to `1`), as `SITE_ID` is set to (inside your `settings.py`).

Comment: Brilliant Thanks Bro

Answer (score 11):

Add `SITE_ID = 1` to settings.py in your django project.

Comment: You should explain in more detail including why

Comment: No, in my case the opposite, removing SITE_ID = 1 from the config did work. What the hell is going on

Comment: literally i spent the full day trying to solve this, reinstalling stuff, playing with migrations and so on.. in the end putting this 1 solved it all.... updates are a nightmare sometimes

Answer (score 7):

I see answers to create a new site and reference id for that. But if you already have a site or somehow you deleted and created the site again from UI then the id keeps on incrementing. To solve this you can get the id as follows:

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
print(Site.objects.get(name='example.com').id)
```

Get the id you get here into `setting.py` . Eg.

```
SITE_ID = 8
```

Basically ID in table corresponding yo tour site and in the settings.py should match.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it without using python `manage.py` shell

At first I tried using the commands above using `manage.py` shell:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
new_site = Site.objects.create(domain='foo.com', name='foo.com')
print(new_site.id)
```

But it gave out an INTEGRITY ERROR

The short answer is add `SITE_ID = 1` to your `settings.py`
If you want to know what your site id is, then go into the actual database, I downloaded sqliteman to see what my table had. So whatever site id you have in the table is what gets assigned to `SITE_ID`

This is because there is a function `get_current` that goes looking for `SITE_ID` and it doesn't find it in your `settings.py`

```
tables
-django_site
--Columns
---id
```

it should have id as 1, name as `example.com`, domain as `example.com`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Query the ID in your database django_site tables and set the right one in your Django settings.py, for example: `SITE_ID = 3`

Answer (score 1):

it seems you fotgot to add
SITE_ID=1
in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while I was creating the sitemap for the project. I included this `'django.contrib.sites'` in the Installed_APP list in the `setting.py` file.
By removing the `'django.contrib.sites'` from the installed_app list the error gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you add site id, below is a sample:

`SITE_ID = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Sites should be accessible via the admin panel once you add `django.contrib.sites` to your app's `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Once you do this, simply access: `<your_django_app_admin_url>/sites/site/`. From there, you can manage sites and see their IDs by accessing a site detail and looking at the browser's URL, which should look similar to `<your_django_app_admin_url>/sites/site/<your_site_id>/change/`.