# Django-allauth No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I am trying to setup **Django-allauth** in my project. I am running into this error and am unable to fix it.

**Environment:**

```
Request Method: GET Request URL: `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/`

Django Version: 1.4.2 Python Version: 2.7.3 
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',  
'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
'django.contrib.sessions',  
'django.contrib.sites', 
'django.contrib.messages',  
'django.contrib.staticfiles',  
'core', 
'allauth',  
'allauth.account',  
'allauth.socialaccount', 
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook', 
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',  
'django.contrib.admin', 
'django.contrib.admindocs')
```

**Installed Middleware:**

```
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error: In template
/media/Dump/Sites/wtr/allauth/templates/socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html,
error at line 3    No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp
using the Django admin    

       1 : {% load socialaccount %}
       2 : 
       3 :  {% providers_media_js %} 
       4 : 
       5 :
```

I actually configured a facebook app in Django Admin but can't understand why it's giving this exception.

```
 Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/login/ Exception
 Value: No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the
 Django admin
```

- I added allauth apps to the `INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS`
- Added that `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting
- Edited the setting, `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`
- Added `allauth` urls in `urls.py`

Is this all that is required to be done or is there some more? If yes, could you please point me to the relevant docs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem could be with your database. Think you need to synchronize the Database.

## DO

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

if that does not work, make sure the `Site` which you added your facebook app to has the domain `localhost:8000` if you are using localhost or `127.0.0.1:8000` if you are using 127.0.0.1:8000

For more information go through this [allauth tutorial](http://techstricks.com/django-allauth-tutorial-step-by-step/).

## UPDATE

you could also try removing the `example.com` site from the admin and add a new site that uses `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000` and add the facebook social app under the new site. Also, do not forget to set the `SITE_ID` variable in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: I tried syncing the db but it didn't work. Actually, I followed the same tutorial with the initial steps :) Looks like 3 other commenters on that post also faced this issue.

Comment: i am quite sure it is to do with the database, if there is not a lot of data in the database maybe remove the database and try recreating the database using `syncdb`

Comment: at your suggestion, I deleted example.com and another dummy site. At first it didn't change anything. After a restart, I ran into a new error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist

After I set my SITE_ID to the correct number, even the facebook authentication started to work. Thanks for taking time to reply.

Comment: @manu, Glad that you managed to solve it, i completely forgot about the `SITE_ID` var, i have updated the answer accordingly for other users. cheers.

Comment: @manu if you found the answer is helpful, mark it as Accepted to close the question.

Comment: To **find the correct SITE_ID** for a site you already created at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/site/ click on the site and [look in the address bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21084927/673991)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue here and the problem was the SITE_ID, which is 1 by default. However, 1 is assigned to the example site that comes by default when you see the admin panel. After creating my site for configuring a Facebook login, I replaced the SITE_ID=2 in settings.py and it worked. Another option is to delete the example site, but it will appear again if at some point you delete your db and create it again.

This took me like 3 hours until I realized... :S

Comment: To **find the correct SITE_ID** for a site you already created at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/site/ click on the site and [look in the address bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21084927/673991)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I think some explanation will help others:
django-allauth uses django-sites which can make it very confusing.

It's very easy to accidentally add sites when you are configuring your social app.

To get things working, you need to make sure that the SITE_ID in your settings matches the domain that you've enabled in your facebook app and selected in the social app on the django back end. If the site specified in any one of these three locations is wrong, you'll get the 'ImproperlyConfigured...' error.

If, like me, you got it all messed up from the start, do this to get facebook authentication working:

1. Go to your facebook app and record the 'Site URL' - This is the only
   site your facebook app will authenticate. For testing I'm using
   '`http://localhost:8000`'. Call this **mysite**.
2. Go to your facebook social app in django admin and make sure you've got **mysite** as the only site in 'chosen sites'. Add it using admin/sites if it's not on the list.
3. Go to admin/sites and delete anything that should not be there.
4. Use phpmyadmin or some such to look at your django_site table and
   record the site_id for **mysite**.
5. Update your settings so that SITE_ID is set to the **mysite** id.

run your server and facebook authentication should work.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problems and thanks everyone for useful suggestions. Here is my solution recipe: (i made `chmod +x manage.py`)

```
1) ./manage.py syncdb
2*) ./manage.py schemamigration --initial socialaccount
(register new app on fb and add new Social app through admin)
3) ./manage.py shell
> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
> site = Site.objects.create(domain='foo.com', name='foo.com')
> site.id
> ^C [y]
4) settings.py > add SITE_ID = 'your site.id'
5) test localhost:8000/accounts/login/
```

*schemamigration  is used with installed South (!)

Comment: I was looking at this backwards.. Gotta read more closely. Thanks to this answer I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

While it may seem obvious, first log into the facebook developer page and create a new app.

[image: facebook developer]

Next go to the djagno [admin site](http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/) and click on the add button for Social Applications.

[image: django admin site]

Save and set up SITE_ID as others have mentioned, so this solved my problem with "No Facebook app configured".

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was, under *Available Sites*, choose (in this case *example.com* which is default SITE_ID name) and add to the right *Chosen Sites*, then save when creating a Social Application

[image: Add the example site to the right pane]

Answer (score 0):

The `site_id` in the settings.py must match the django admin entry for your site (during testing it might be localhost:8000).  This is located in the "sites" choice under the "sites" heading (again, in the admin).  To get your `site_id`... click on "sites". Note: just because you have 2 entries and the 2nd is yours doesn't mean the `site_id = 2`.  Click on your entry and then note in the address bar the number.  This is covered above and elsewhere, but being new to coding I needed more explicit instructions.
[see the 3 in the pic?  Well it was my 2nd of 2 entries in "sites"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LkKR.png)