# django-allauth: No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

i saw some topic about my problem however i didn' t find the solution for it and i don' t know what i' m doing wrong.

Since this is a test system,

- i delete my whole db
- i run syncdb && migrate to have everything clear.
- i set the SITE_ID to 1
- i restart apache2 (well, not using development server at the moment)
- in the admin -> Sites -> Sites section i set the example.com to mysub.mydomain.com (for both the display name and domain name)
- in the admin -> Socialaccount -> Social apps section i add a new app:

  - provider: facebook
  - name: the same name than on developers.facebook.com
  - client id: App ID/API Key from developers.facebook.com
  - Key: stays None
  - Secret: App Secret from developers.facebook.com
  - Chosen sites: i move here the only one existing which is mysub.mydomain.com (on developers.facebook.com i' ve the same mysub.mydomain.com at App Domains)
- in the settings.py file i' ve these relevant sections:

  - MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )
  - INSTALLED_APPS = (...,
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook', 
    )
  - TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('common.context_processors.add_app_name',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',)
  - AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )
  - SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    { 'facebook':
    { 'SCOPE': ['email'],
      'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
      'METHOD': 'oauth2',
      'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
    }
    }
- to the urls.py: url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

. After all these (and apache2 restart) when i go to mysub.mydomain.com/accounts/login/ (i log out from admin at first) i got the same error than for example here:

[Django-allauth No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019017/django-allauth-no-facebook-app-configured-please-add-a-socialapp-using-the-djan)

. I don' t really know what else can be the problem but i' d be happy if someone could point me to the right direction or to tell me what else to check.

Thanks.

Comment: It' s very strange, but for today - without any modification - it became good... . Well, no idea.