# django-allauth SITE_ID error

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm learning django and have decided to use django-allauth for user registration. I currently only want local accounts (I've excluded social auth from settings.py).

When I access `/accounts/login` I get the following error:

> You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the
>   SITE_ID setting. Create a site in your database and set the SITE_ID
>   setting to fix this error.

The Official Django docs say:

> The ID, as an integer, of the current site in the django_site database
>   table. This is used so that application data can hook into specific
>   sites and a single database can manage content for multiple sites.

But I don't quite understand this. Right now I'm just running django in a development environment, and normally just doing `python manage.py runserver` gets things running and I can test my app.

How do I fix this `SITE_ID` issue with local accounts? Would the solution be different in production/development environments?

Comment: Have you set SITE_ID=1 in settings.py?  That is usually a default setting in the settings.py file, but if you are using another module, you may have to add that.

Comment: Maybe this help for you
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019017/django-allauth-no-facebook-app-configured-please-add-a-socialapp-using-the-djan?answertab=active#tab-top][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019017/django-allauth-no-facebook-app-configured-please-add-a-socialapp-using-the-djan?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding "SITE_ID = 1" to your settings will get you past the exception 
without having to add it to INSTALLED_APPS. It worked for me.

Comment: This is a correct solution. It helped me get rid of the error. I am surprised that this is not mentioned in Django Docs or probably I missed it.

Comment: @ShwetabhSharan It's described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)

Comment: I have the same problem. Where I must write SITE_ID = 1 in settings file, I do  not understand where exactly?

Answer (score 1):

FYI.  Enabling the sites framework has been changed in Django v1.6 see here for details...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/sites/

Once you have added 'django.contrib.sites', to your INSTALLED_APPS then the domain will be created in the database, id = 1, domain = example.com, name = example.com.