# How to get to an interactive SQLite command-line prompt in PyCharm Pro with a Django project?

Tags: django, command-line, sqlite, pycharm

My Django project uses an SQLite3 database.  How can I get to the SQLite [command line shell](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)?  PyCharm has lots of other handy interactive windows

- manage.py [utility console](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-tasks-of-manage-py-utility.html)
- Python [console](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/interactive-console.html)
- `sqlite3>` ??

Why would I want to do this?  I've already figured out [how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21084806/673991) to get the SITE_ID.  But this would have helped with that.  I want to look under the hood for [other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82875/673991).

I've already tried View | Tool Window | Database | right-click | Console, but that's not really a command line interface.

I want to be able to type `.help` somewhere and get to know my database.

Answer (score 1):

The db interface (i.e. only allowing proper SQL like `SELECT` and so on) seems to be the only way to communicate to the db via pycharm.

I'd recommend just using the terminal for this. Type `./manage.py dbshell` and you have what you want. Move the terminal to the left and you got sort of the the built in db connection offers. Or to the right, or top, or whereever you want.

Comment: Thanks, but from my manage.py window (Ctrl-Alt-R) dbshell closes that window and brings up two Django Consoles.  Though `manage.py dbshell` works great from the windows command line (Alt-F12).