# Specify database to use in Django

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases, django-settings

I need to use multiple databases for my django project. The application works fine when there is only one database:

In setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',                     
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                     
        'PORT': 3306,    
    },
```

But if I added more databases from the same engine:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{},
    'mydb1': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
            'NAME': 'mydb1',    
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                    
            'PORT': 3306,                  
        },
   'mydb2': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
            'NAME': 'mydb2',           
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',             
            'PORT': 3306,                   
                }
    }
```

it gives me following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Also, i tried:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
                'NAME': 'mydb1',    
                'USER': 'root',
                'PASSWORD': '',
                'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                    
                'PORT': 3306,                  
            },
       'mydb2': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
                'NAME': 'mydb2',           
                'USER': 'root',
                'PASSWORD': '',
                'HOST': '127.0.0.1',             
                'PORT': 3306,                   
                    }
        }
```

It only sees mydb1, not mydb2, when i tried query mydb2, it gives me:

```
DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Do I need to define database route? it seems that I only need to do that for customized read/write.

Thanks

## UPDATE:

In django docs, it says "The default routing scheme ensures that if a database isn't specified, all queries fall back to the default database".

So I guess my actual question is  **how do I specify a database to use for my queries?**

Comment: Did you find out how to select the database in the end?

Answer (score 1):

It is explicetely stated in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases)

> The DATABASES setting must configure a default database; any number of
>   additional databases may also be specified.
>
> If the concept of a default database doesn’t make sense in the context
>   of your project, you need to be careful to always specify the database
>   that you want to use.

As in your second example default database is not configured

```
DATABASES = {
     'default':{},
...
}
```

when you access your data with no database specified, a `django.db.backends.dummy` backend is used, which complains on your configuration with `ImproperlyConfigured` error.

An example of configuring multiple database usage with Database Routers can be [found in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example)

**update**

Site matching query error is for completely different reasons, and is another question. Answer here, as it is duplicate of many others: as your `mysql1` and `mysql2` dbs have different content, second one seems to not to be properly configured. Refer [site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814271/1265154).

Comment: The second example django docs gives for multiple databases left it empty:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: I can specify database to update when syncdb --databases=mydb2, but how do i specify a database while accessing data? Is it done in model.py?

Comment: @zyenge see last link to docs in my answer, this **can't be done** in model, it is done via `DATABASE_ROUTERS` setting

Comment: So customized db_for_read/write or not, a `DATABASE_ROUTERS` **must** be used when there are multiple databases? That was my original question...

Comment: @zyenge Sorry, I don't get meaning of `So customized db_for_read/write or not, a database_route must be used when there are multiple databases?` And see updates about site not defined.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about the question. I thought DATABASE_ROUTERS is used when I have multiple databases in my backend **and** I want to specify a database to write to, and another one to read from. But if all I need is to access all my databases, I don't need to customize which one to read, which one to write, do I still need to define DATABASE_ROUTERS? Is there a way to access multiple databases as if all tables are in one db?