# "django-rest-auth" DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using [django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) for facebook integration with android as front-end. I followed all the steps mentioned in integrating [django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

I have only one SITE and set SITE_ID to 1

I have also set Client ID and Secret ID of my app and made sure i have choosen my site.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Below is my code

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
]
```

My custom Login Serializer

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'cut_veggie_user.serializers.NormalUserSerializer',
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1
```

In the urls I have also included the FacebookLogin

```
urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(),       name='fb_login'),
          ]
```

Can anyone tell my what am i missing?

Comment: please describe the error or issue you are running into

Comment: This is the error i get, DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the problem finally.

I followed the below steps

> python manage.py shell

then i got the site id for my website by this command

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
new_site = Site.objects.create(domain='foo.com', name='foo.com')
print new_site.id
```

and added the id to SITE_ID in settings.py

To my surprise i got the site id as 3, which i am not sure why.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist?answertab=votes#tab-top) post

Answer (score 0):

This Error is may be due the email verification. Add this code in your settings.py file.

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False

And now authentication will work.