# Django App Deploy on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Error: relation "django_site" does not exist

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using this popular tutorial to deploy a django app on AWS EB.
https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

After deploying I am getting the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /accounts/login/
relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
```

Fixes others have suggested that I have done:

- I have 'django.contrib.sites' in my installed apps (settings.py)
- I have SITE_ID = 1 in settings

Some are suggesting that you run manage.py migrate sites before migrating the rest of the tables.

Does anyone know how to do that on an AWS instance? I SSH'd in and that command won't run.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I've been battling AWS Elastic Beanstalk for a week now.

Comment: Could you update your question with the error you get when trying to run `./manage.py migrate sites` on the AWS instance?

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed my Django project using Apache recently, and ran into a similar problem as I got the error about the Site not existing.

You have to create a "site", in your database, and chose it's domain and a name for it. Then, in your settings.py file, you should add the SITE_ID number corresponding to the "site" you've just created (which can actually be 1 but might take other values), and it should run properly if everything's done correctly.

I've learned this from an answer here on Stack Overflow, it explains the commands you need to run to acheive this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814271/6857994

Good luck