# Using two settings (prod and dev) with django site, dev doesn't allow admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Currently I am using two separate settings.  One of them is the prod settings file that I upload to heroku in every push(postgres).  The other one I use for development(sqlite3).  All works well in production (thank heavens) however, the admin site doesn't work in production.

I am using `python manage.py --settings=djangoroot.devsettings` to run the dev server. However, the admin site is giving me the following:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

Here is my devsettings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'c(s+3-(=_22lr86m)6km!kn&q9irg7fn$19=--wl*p=)k_bgl&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['djangoandreact.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'articles'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoroot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoroot.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using **`'django.contrib.sites'`** in your **`INSTALLED_APPS`** , you should set/add **`SITE_ID=1`** in your `devsettings`

**Reference**
1. [Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388746/8283848)