# django sitemap DoesNotExist at /sitemap.xml

Tags: python, django, django-sitemaps

when i add sitemap to my Django project i got this error ..

DoesNotExist at /sitemap.xml

> Site matching query does not exist.

sitemap.py :

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from .models import Homepage


class DynamicSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Homepage.objects.all()
```

url.py :

```
from first_app.sitemaps import DynamicSitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

sitemaps = {'dynamic': DynamicSitemap()}

urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap , {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemaps'),
]
```

settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
    'first_app',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
```

]

any help and thanks

[image]

Comment: Please show your folder structure. Where is this url.py stored?

Comment: in project folder first_project/urls.py

Comment: Please show your folder structure.

Comment: this is screenshot for structure in photo

https://filebin.net/mlf7cyme2j8ld0e5/e.png?t=oqocm3nm

Comment: my file in 
first_project/urls.py

Comment: If this is a project-level  urls.py it is supposed to have other urlpatterns like homepage and so on. Does it? Do you have ROOT_URLCONF defined? Does any other url work?

Comment: this is the full code in urls.py file and yes the other urls work fine

take a look please 
https://filebin.net/iqojfkrjx93audi6/urls.py?t=kij53hdq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5257129/Why-does-my-sitemap-xml-page-return-django-issue-r) comment out the **'django.contrib.sites'** in the settings.py file under **INSTALLED_APPS** solve this problem.

Answer (score 11):

You can try to add **`SITE_ID = 1`** above **INSTALLED_APPS**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer stated in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5257129/Why-does-my-sitemap-xml-page-return-django-issue-r) is wrong. To fix this, you just need to add `SITE_ID = 1` to your `settings.py`. That will do the trick.