# My python code is working on gitpod however it prompt DoesNotExist in deployment

Tags: python, gitpod

I'm new in heroku and I get error here need help.
I've write python code in gitpod and runserver everything is working, when i deployed to heroku admin and login pages show DoesNotExist at /admin/login/, Site matching query does not exist.

I've try to clear cache
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
$ heroku builds:cache:purge -a myscubaworkshop

then git commit changes and push heroku master

still the same outcome and build log :
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.9.5

Can anyone help?
https://myscubaworkshop.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Comment: Did you try to check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814059/site-matching-query-does-not-exist

Comment: Thanks @EgorWexler I'll check out now.

Comment: Hi @EgorWexler, I've try to follow the solution from python shell from django.contrib.sites.models import Site, it gave me INTEGRITY ERROR.

Then I check SITE_ID is equal to 1 which is match to my setting.py.

Comment: I see that you're using sites framework. Do you really need it? you can check more information here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/